# OpenEdx 500 Server error after installing Custom them

Tags: bitnami, openedx

Already posted in Bitnami community. www.community.bitnami.com/t/500-server-error-after-installing-custom-theme/52736

I'm trying to install a open edx theme from 
Links: **www.github(dot)com/dadasoz/edx-bootstrap-theme**. and following steps at
 **docs.bitnami(dot)com/installer/apps/edx/#how-to-install-a-custom-standford-theme**

** I'm getting 500 internal server error.

Apache Logs

[Wed Oct 18 00:51:26.682720 2017] [:error] [pid 25207]   File "/opt/bitnami/apps/edx/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 890, in _exec_template
[Wed Oct 18 00:51:26.682723 2017] [:error] [pid 25207]     callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)
[Wed Oct 18 00:51:26.682726 2017] [:error] [pid 25207]   File "/tmp/mako_lms/cd6b613ed628f9f43e33fb106119f020/edx-bootstrap-theme/lms/templates/main.html.py", line 293, in render_body
[Wed Oct 18 00:51:26.682729 2017] [:error] [pid 25207]     runtime._include_file(context, (static.get_template_path('header.html')), _template_uri, online_help_token=online_help_token)
[Wed Oct 18 00:51:26.682733 2017] [:error] [pid 25207]   File "/opt/bitnami/apps/edx/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 752, in _include_file
[Wed Oct 18 00:51:26.682736 2017] [:error] [pid 25207]     callable_(ctx, **_kwargs_for_include(callable_, context._data, **kwargs))
[Wed Oct 18 00:51:26.682739 2017] [:error] [pid 25207]   File "/tmp/mako_lms/cd6b613ed628f9f43e33fb106119f020/edx-bootstrap-theme/lms/templates/header.html.py", line 34, in render_body
[Wed Oct 18 00:51:26.682742 2017] [:error] [pid 25207]     runtime._include_file(context, (static.get_themed_template_path(relative_path='theme-header.html', default_path='theme-header.html')), _template_uri, online_help_token=online_help_token)
[Wed Oct 18 00:51:26.682746 2017] [:error] [pid 25207]   File "/opt/bitnami/apps/edx/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 625, in **getattr**
[Wed Oct 18 00:51:26.682749 2017] [:error] [pid 25207]     (self.name, key))
[Wed Oct 18 00:51:26.682752 2017] [:error] [pid 25207] AttributeError: Namespace 'static' has no member 'get_themed_template_path'

My site is down now.Can someone please help me in fixing the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have reached the same error, trying to find more information about the case, I have seen in the theme GitHub repository there is an [open issue](https://github.com/dadasoz/edx-bootstrap-theme/issues/4#issuecomment-253975099) in which it is said that this theme is not compatible with *Eucalyptus*.

If your instance is not very old you'll be using *Ficus* which is the current version released by Bitnami, if the previous version (*Eucalyptus*) is not compatible with this theme, I'm afraid *Ficus* will not be either.